# jQuery Cookie saving FORM values when .Change()

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am passing the `FORM` values to a cookie via jQuery Cookie. Am I doing something wrong I can not get the cookie values to save

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
;(function ($) {
    $('input[name="FirstName"]').change(function(){
        $.cookie("FirstName", $('input[name="FirstName"]').val();, {path: "/", domain: "domain.com"});
    });
    $('input[name="LastName"]').change(function(){
        $.cookie("LastName", $('input[name="LastName"]').val();, {path: "/", domain: "domain.com"});
    });
    $('input[name="Email"]').change(function(){
        $.cookie("Email", $('input[name="Email"]').val();, {path: "/", domain: "domain.com"});
    });
    $('input[name="Category"]').change(function(){
        $.cookie("Category", $('select[name="Category"]').val();, {path: "/", domain: "domain.com"});
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method='post' action='send.php' name='demo'>
 <input type='text' name='FirstName' value='' id='FirstName' />
 <input type='text' name='LastName' value='' id='LastName' />
 <input type='text' name='Email value='' id='Email' />
 <select name='Category'>
  <option value='Blue'>Blue</option>
  <option value='Red'>Red</option>
  <option value='Green'>Green</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code, remove the `;`:

```
$.cookie("FirstName", $('input[name="FirstName"]').val();, {path: "/", domain: "domain.com"});
                                                // ---- ^
```

Also note that `;(function ($) { ... })(jQuery)` is a closure, it doesn't do what document ready handler does.

```
jQuery(function($) { // The first argument of the document ready handler refers to jQuery
    $('input, select').change(function(){
        $.cookie(this.name, this.value, {path: "/", domain: "domain.com"});
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks... also is $(window).load(function() needed ?

Comment: @acctman No. It doesn't help here. Using DOMReady is sufficient.